# The method getApplicationContext() - how to use without Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a async task called within an activity:

```
    public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
```

Because of that there's some things I cannot do, one of those it's using getApplicationContext()

There's any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your application context in to the constructor

```
public DownloadFile(Context context)
{
    // Do fun stuff with the context, such as assign it to a class variable
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either have a constructor that has context as a parameter - That way you could call it from an activity using

```
DownloadFile df = new DownloadFile(this);
```

Or you could just use

```
ActivityClass.this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do `ActivityName.this`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a reference to your activity like:

Context ctx = YourActivityName.this;

Answer (score 0):

Would passing the context from the Activity class to the AsyncTask's constructor class do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using an Activity as a Context, use ApplicationContext instead; it will help you avoid memory leaks caused by Activity leaks - read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

That said, use YourActivityName.this.getApplicationContext();

Comment: You can use a WeakReference<Context> member to avoid leaks. If the Context is finalized before the end of the AsyncTask, there's a big problem.